# Copy Smartsheet row with attachments

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I keep trying to copy a line from one sheet to another with the row attachments.  The attachments copy automatically when rows are moved between sheets, but not when copied.  The API documentation states that there is an "include" parameter that can be set to "all", and that this will cause attachments to be copied as well.  Would anyone be willing to provide a sample of this parameter and how to write it into something like the following?

apologies if this is basic python.  I am new to the language and very new to api.

```
response = smart.Sheets.copy_rows( 
    18382041966468,
    smart.models.CopyOrMoveRowDirective({
        'row_ids': [7372751113086852],
        'to': smart.models.CopyOrMoveRowDestination({
            'sheet_id': 4433677678602116
        })
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `include` attribute is the third argument you provide to the `copy_rows` method after the `CopyOrMoveRowDirective` where you set the `row_ids` and destination sheet. It takes a comma-separated list of row elements to copy in addition to the cell data. I found this looking at the `copy_rows` method in the SDK [here](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/smartsheet/sheets.py#L187).
You can also just set a single string. Your code with the `include='all'` would look like this:

```py
response = smart.Sheets.copy_rows( 
    18382041966468,
    smart.models.CopyOrMoveRowDirective({
        'row_ids': [7372751113086852],
        'to': smart.models.CopyOrMoveRowDestination({
            'sheet_id': 4433677678602116
        })
    }),
    include='all'
)
```

To do this with a list for include you could set it like this:

```py
response = smar_client.Sheets.copy_rows(
  4453526869960580,               # sheet_id of rows to be copied
  smar_client.models.CopyOrMoveRowDirective({
    'row_ids': [1874694623782788],
    'to': smar_client.models.CopyOrMoveRowDestination({
      'sheet_id': 1955951847729028
    })
  }),
  include=['attachments','discussions']
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it.  The documentation mentioned that this parameter was a list of elements.  I was taking that as a literal python list.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped. You can provide a list instead of a string value if you want to add multiple values for include instead of just all. You could set include to equal a list with strings for discussions and attachments if you want just those for example. I just edited my answer to have that and show an example of using a list for include instead of just the string value for all.